# Displaying Bags after using FILTER in apachepig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My data is in the form of:

```
{Type,                Category,             Region,      Attack on}
(Enemy Action,        Direct Fire,          RC EAST,     ENEMY)
(Friendly Action,     Cache Found/Cleared,  RC EAST,     FRIEND)
(Non-Combat Event,    Propaganda,           RC SOUTH,    NEUTRAL)
(Suspicious Incident, Surveillance,         RC CAPITAL,  ENEMY)
(Explosive Hazard,    IED Explosion,        RC SOUTH,    ENEMY)
```

so my task is to Examine all events that involve explosive hazards.

Loading the data into a bag with this:

```
a = load '/home/training/Desktop/Project2/afganwardata/afghan.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (details:tuple(type:chararray, category:chararray,region:chararray, attack:chararray));
```

Filtering the given data for explosive hazards by doing

```
fila = FILTER a by details.type=='Explosive Hazard';
```

to display the results im using

```
dispa = FOREACH fila GENERATE details.type,details.category,details.region,details.attack;
```

After I display the results using

```
dump dispa;
```

it shows this:

> Input(s):
>   Successfully read records from: `"/home/training/Desktop/Project2/afganwardata/afghan.csv"`
>
> Output(s):
>   Successfully stored records in: `"file:/tmp/temp-1199379753/tmp-1030236329"`

But it does not show me the required output.

Am I missing some steps or doing something wrong?
Please help!

Comment: the size of the record stored will be zero, may be the filter command is not true for any case. Check the output for dump fila, may be you get the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are inserting tuple which is already split with comma(,). You don't need to mention in script;

```
a = load '/home/training/Desktop/Project2/afganwardata/afghan.csv' AS (details:(type:chararray, category:chararray,region:chararray, attack:chararray));

fila = FILTER a by details.type=='Explosive Hazard';

dispa = FOREACH fila GENERATE details.type,details.category,details.region,details.attack;

Dump dispa;
```

output

(Explosive Hazard,IED Explosion,RC SOUTH,ENEMY)